# DataGridView and Refreshing The Data On Changes

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an application with a DataGridView it, it is simply a set of columns and 3 buttons.

When I select the 'Get Lead' Button I wish to have the 'Assigned' column change to 'Assigned' which I have got working fine as the get Lead button updates the SQL Table in the Background.

What it doesn't do is update the DataGridView in realtime, so I added a TableAdapter.Fill Method after I do the button press, the problem here is it moves the location of the cursor and redraws the entire DataGridView.

While it accomplishes what I want, it looks poor from a user point of view.

How can I resolve this so if my scroll bars were moved over and I chose 'Get Lead' and the column changed to 'Assign' that the DataGridView reflects the data in the database immediately without 'redrawing' the DataGridView.

This is my code for when I click the button in question:

```
Private Sub LeadsDGV_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles LeadsDGV.CellContentClick

    Try

        Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            If LeadsDGV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "GetLeadBtn" Then
                LMSMainTableAdapter.GetLead(ActiveDirectory.ADUsername, LeadsDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value())
            ElseIf LeadsDGV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "AssignLeadBtn" Then
                'MsgBox("Row Index " & e.RowIndex & " Column: " & LeadsDGV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)
            ElseIf LeadsDGV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "DelLeadBtn" Then
                LMSMainTableAdapter.DeleteLead(ActiveDirectory.ADUsername, LeadsDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value())
                LMSMainTableAdapter.Fill(LMSDataset.LMS_MainLeads)
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Logging.ReportError(ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save current cell info before calling `Fill` method:

```
Dim intCurrentRow As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
Dim intCurrentColumn As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
```

And restore this info after using `Fill`:

```
Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(intCurrentRow).Cells(intCurrentColumn)
```